# Работа с переменными из подгружаемого скрипта

Tags: javascript, userjs

То есть Userjs.

На странице сайта есть переменная, допустим:

```
var one = 1;
```

С юзерскрипта в опере я могу перехватить эту переменную так:

```
window.one
```

В хроме и лисе так не могу. Каким образом можно еще перехватить?

Comment: А вам обязательно с юзерскрипта надо? С консоли все прекрасно подхватывается.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы имеете ввиду изменение переменной через адресную строку, то могу сказать, что существует еще, как минимум 1 способ перехвата и изменения переменной - это просто залезть в подключаемый JS-скрипт и сделать свое коварное дело =) В браузере Google Chrome для таких вещей создан очень удобный инструмент, вызывается он на **F12**. Там можно отследить, куда обращается программа при передаче формы, например. Или просмотреть всю структуру сайта, в виде дерева файлов.

Если же вы имели ввиду не адресную строку, то скажу, что JS-Скрипт можно выполнять и в ней. Сделать это очень просто: написать в начале адресной строки `"javascript:"` и затем уже выполнять какой-либо код. Например, этот выводит мэсседж:

```
 javascript: alert('')
```

Если же вам надо просто спрятать значение вашей переменной one, то сделать это можно с помощью обфускатора( [один из них](http://www.javascriptobfuscator.com/default.aspx) ). Или же придумать свой хитроумный способ прятания значения переменной.

Comment: Ему из браузерного расширения необходимо прочитать (а может и записать) значение глобальной переменной, принадлежащей странице.

Comment: @Qwertiy, спустя почти 5 лет, ему, скорее всего, уже ничего не необходимо :)